# Php folder-file creation encoding issues

Tags: php, cakephp, utf-8, character-encoding, cakephp-3.0

I am having issues creating files and folder using cakephp 3's [Folder and File libraries](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/file-folder.html) (though it's php's mkdir in the back end of this).

**PHP version is 7.0.28**

The steps:

1. User uploads file (in Greek characters)
2. System handles some irrelevant validation etc
3. System creates path to save the file in a custom folder and save the location in a database table looking like this: `documents. DS . $user->username . DS . $file->protocol . $file->file_type . DS . $file->name`
   An example path would look like

> /documents/user/Κ.300/Κ.310_6_4092.pdf

3. On my ubuntu environment it works fine, however on windows server 2012 R2 the greek character parts look like they have encoding issues, like so (apologies for the bad quality)[image]

I have tried a number of things and here is what I know so far:

- Ubuntu 16.04 uses UTF-8 encoding same as php which is why the folder looks fine on my dev environment.
- Windows uses UTF-16 (I believe, i'm not 100% sure) which is what i should convert it to, but when I try to convert the path to utf-16 I get the following iconv error or the greek characters appear like question marks and php fails to create the directory:

> illegal input sequence at position

Here is 
the underlying code:

```
public function setPath(array $data)
{
    Configure::load('file_directories', 'default');
    $path = $this->createPathFromData($data);
    $folder = new Folder('/');
    $folder->create($path);
    $this->directory = new Folder($path);
    if (!$this->validateDirectory()) {
        throw new Exception('Something went wrong when creating directories');
    }
}
```

Here are some debugging outputs:

```
debug(mb_detect_encoding($path));
```

> UTF-8

```
debug($path);
debug(iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', $path));
```

> '/inbox/documents/someUser/εξερχομενο/Κ.900'
>
> '��/inbox/documents/someUser/����������/�.900'

```
debug(iconv('UTF-8', 'GREEK', $path));
```

> 'inbox/documents/someUser/���������/�.900'

```
debug(iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1252', $path));
```

> [https://secure.php.net/function.iconv'>function.iconv]: Detected an illegal character in input string

When I enter either of the converted encoding paths to `$folder->create($path)` i still get bogus paths if I get any at all.

How can I create the proper files and file paths for windows Server 2012 xampp?

***UPDATE***

After several more hours of testing, it appears as in my windows server the data in Greek characters i'm sending through a form do not appear properly, as windows displays them through Windows-1251 encoding.
In phpmyadmin they all appear right, but if i put a break point in the middle of my system running, they appear similarly to the screenshot I have shown. Furthermore, the character-set of my response headers are `Windows-1251` for windows, `utf-8` for ubuntu. So I tried converting my utf-8 data to windows-1252 but still, my greek input turns into question marks. Still no solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those suffering from the same problem as I did, mainly Greek developers here's the answer to creating folders and files with Greek names from user input:

1. Change the system locale to Greek (or the language you desire) like [so](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml)
2. When you get input via form (assuming the input encoding is UTF-8) convert it to ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1253. If you convert it to Windows-1253 you can only use php's function iconv. For ISO-8859-1 you can use mb_convert_econding. Like so:

   `$input = iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1253', $input)`

   OR

   `$input = mb_convert_encoding($input, 'ISO-8859-1')`
3. Now you are ready to create your folder in Greek. Bear in mind that Windows-1252 or Windows-1251 **DO NOT** support Greek characters and Windows-1253 only displays them properly if you change the system locale to Greek too.
4. **You are not done!** Depending on your database encoding (in my case it was UTF-8) you **HAVE** to convert the string back to UTF-8 if you plan on storing it. Or you could make a copy at the very beginning. In any case, do not store the converted input in your database or you will end up with a bunch of stored gibberish.

I hope this saves someone the trouble I had to go through!